# How to show MacLaurin series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ converges using remainder term

Tags: taylor-expansion

$\dfrac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$ this is valid for $x$ between $-1$ and $1$ not including the endpoints.

How can one show that the Lagrange remainder goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity? Just trying to understand. Presumably it should go to zero.

Comment: I think one can get it by bare Lagrange only for $x\gt -1/2$.

Comment: I once tried this as an example when teaching calculus without having thought about it ahead of time. Needless to say, it didn't work out nicely.

Comment: I imagine not! Feel sorry for you there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "Lagrange remainder". Simply take the difference of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and the partial sum $1+x+x^2+...+x^n$ and you will see that it goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k
$,
$\frac{1}{1-x}
-\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k
=\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$.

What is needed is to show that,
for any $x \in(-1, 1)$,
$\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.

For a fixed $x$,
this is equivalent to showing that
$x^n \to 0$.

It is enough to show this for $x > 0$
(why?).

Watch closely - the fingers never leave the hands.

Let $x = \frac{1}{1+b}$
where $b = \frac1{x}-1 > 0$.
$(1+b)^n
> nb$
(by Bernoulli's inequality)
so
$x^n
=\frac{1}{(1+b)^n}
< \frac1{nb}
\to 0
$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: How is that using the Lagrange remainder? That's not what I asked. But thanks. I guess it must be impossible to use Lagrange remainder, perhaps it is only a sufficient condition for convergence and not a necessary one?